# Android Stop a service form a service

Tags: android, service, altbeacon

I can't stop my service.

I have two services. Service1 starts Service2 with startService(intent).
I stop service1 with stopSelf();
Then I'm doing something in Service2 and start Service1 again and stop Service2.

So they are always starting each other again.

The behavior of the services are different after the first start.

I write some log messages and I can see that the information are multiply times in log cat.

I also tried to stop the activities in the onStartCommand of the other activty with stopService. (In onStartCommand of Service1 I call stopService service2)

Here is a Part of my Code:

Service1:

```
public class Service1 extends Service{
    private int startId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();   
    }

    private void doSomething(){
        ...
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service2.class);
        startService(intent);
        this.stopSelf(startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.startId=startId;

        Intent beaconIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service2.class);
        stopService(beaconIntent);

        doSomething();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Service2:

```
public class Service2 extends Service implements BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier{ 
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager; 
    private int startId;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service1.class);
        stopService(service1);

        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
        mBeaconManager.bind(this);

        this.startId = startId;

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        region = new Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null);
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);         
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this); 
    }

    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {        
        if(!beacons.isEmpty()){  
            doSomething...
            ...
            ...
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service1.class);
            startService(intent);

            this.stopSelf();                
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I didn't mention, that I'm working with altbeacon library. I thought that doesn't make any impact. 
But when I'm looking at the services which are running when I start the app and after I stop the Service2 there are always two altbeacon services running(BeaconIntentProcessor and BeaconService). 
Maybe they calling my service mutlipy times.

Comment: `"What I'm doing worng?"` you are not positing your sources

Comment: what is condition of starting Service1?

Comment: I added some Code.

@Elias Fazel: What do you mean with condition of Service1? I stop both services after I start the other service. So it should only run one service per time.

Comment: I recommend to replace stopSelft with stopService(new Intent(...));

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The Service2 is still running multiply times. 
I didn't mention, that I'm working with altbeacon library. I thought that doesn't make any impact. 
But when I'm looking at the services which are running when I start the app and after I stop the Service2 there are always two altbeacon services running(BeaconIntentProcessor and BeaconService). 
Maybe they calling my service mutlipy times... 
I will add the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I did wrong.

The problem was not the service it self, it was the altbeacon library. More concrete the BeaconManager which was still searching in the background for a beacon, even when the service was destroyed.
In the logs it looked like the service is running multiple times.

The solution was to not only unbind, also to stop Ranging and remove the range notifier.

```
mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
```